# Salesforce Batch Apex Class - Querying Against Large Data Sets

Tags: collections, batch-file, salesforce, force.com

I have a batch apex class where i'm building collections of websites and emails, so that i can use those collections to filter other other queries which will be made into collections. With all collections set, i want to run through a final loop of the scope to perform business processes.

Mockup:

```
for(Object o : scope)
{
listEmails.add(o.Email);
listWebsites.add(o.Websites);
}

Map<String, Account> accounts = Gather all accounts where website not in :listWebsties; //Website is key
List<String, Contact> contacts = Gather all contacts where email not in :listEmails; //Email is key

for(Object o : scope)
{
   Account = accounts.get(o.website);
   Contact = contacts.get(o.Email);

   Perform business logic here
}
```

The problem is when i run this batch it stays processing for hours. When working with a rather small database this works fine. But in working in a larger environment perhaps this is not the best solution.

Can anyone help me speed up the batch process with a more effective approach?

Comment: When you run the batch, what is the batch size you supply? `Id BatchId = Database.executeBatch(Batch,[What is this number?]);` Also, can you post the debug-log summary for your batch, it looks like: `Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100 \n Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000.. etc.` These pieces of data will help in determining how you can speed it up.

Comment: I don't supply a batch size. The scope for the first process i ran was only 300 records. So a collection of 300 list items is used for filtering the other objects queried ie Accounts and Contacts. It's those other objects which are queried that is slowing the process dramatically.

Comment: The default batch size is 200, i.e. everything you get query for in the start() method is broken into lists of 200, and 200 items are passed to scope at any one time. You can't process everything in the main query in one go, so I suspect you may need to rework your logic to account for this.

Comment: I just noticed that in the psuedo code i used NOT IN. That's my mistake the actual code is filtering for the Accounts and the Contacts that are IN the list collections. This is what is so weird to me, why is the batch process taking so long to run when all i'm trying to do is build list of emails and websites, then build a collections of accounts and contacts with those emails and websites so that i can reference those objects in the latter scope loop. 
I want to reference the account and contact records which match the website or email of the final scope records.
The batch is taking too long.

Comment: Are you at all using salesforce batch processing (as mentioned by Matthew and Lacey) or do you just call your process a batch?

Comment: I am indeed using an apex batch class.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway to post the entire batch apex class? Or help understand the data more?
It looks like from your map that all of your accounts (in theory) have unique websites and all of your contacts have unique emails?
I assume you build those maps by hand? That is you loop over the accounts and do a 
map.put(account.website,account)?

Do you have any system debug statements to confirm your map sizes?
What happens if there is no account or no contact when you call accounts.get()?

And the business logic - is it more looping?

And are you using Batch variables in a static manner - i.e. you can have a counter to count the total number of records processed. If so, is your variable a list? that can be dangerous of course.

Also what object is your scope object? Not that it matters, but I'd think you'd want to have your scope be the Accounts themselves or the Contacts themselves.

I'd try adding system.debug statements to your batch to verify it's running and to see where the infinite loop may be occurring.